# Can a Windows Phone 8 device be used for testing apps built with WP SDK 7.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

The short story is: I have my laptop that has a processor without Virtualization and Second Level Adress Translation capabilities that are required for running the new Windows Phone 8 SDK.

I can however use the windows phone 7.1 sdk, but for testing my apps i will use a windows phone 8 device.

Is it possible to deploy and test my apps on the connected WP8 device, altough i am using the 7.1 SDK that predates the WP8 os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to deploy apps using WP7.1 SDK on WP8 devices, however, you can install the Visual Studio 2012 + Windows Phone 8 SDK (if you have Windows 8 x64) even when you don't have SLAT enabled CPU. The Windows Phone 8 SDK will work, only you won't be able to launch the WP8 emulator.

Comment: i did not know that, however i own a Intel Core2Duo T6600 procesor wich does not even support virtalization, will i still be able to use the SDK without the emulator?

Comment: @Freeman - Why are you asking if you will be able to use the SDK without the emulator, Martin said exactly that.

Comment: Because virtualization is not the same thing as SLAT. He replied for SLAT and i asked about Virtualization.

Comment: SLAT is required for running Hyper-V and virtualizing the WP8 emulators, so yes, you will be able to run the WP8 SDK and WP7 emulators, but not the Hyper-V or WP8 emulators.

Comment: Thank you Martin, you understood my question.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, The .xap packing mechanism in Windows phone 7.1 and 8 are different so you cannot deploy this xap using deployment tool. But, if we are using windows 8 + wp8 dev tools you can debug the application that developed on 7.1. In future after the launch of wp 7.8 ms may provide a solution for this. for now there is no other alternative is available in front  of you

Comment: well, regardless the xap packing mechanism it would theoretically be possible to deploy a wp 7.1 app to a wp 8 device since wp 7.5 can be run on wp8 devices.

Comment: But i don' think it is going to work on windows 7. I tried this before but failed.

Comment: i am running windows 8 as my pc os, dont understand what do you mean by "don' think it is going to work on windows 7".

Comment: @Freeman - Except then it would be a WP 7.5 application not a WP8 application which means your limited in what languages you can use to develop it in.

Comment: Excellent, thats what i wanted to know, anyway i am more happy that my apps will work for 7.5 also as those devices are not deprecated.